# Where can I learn more about "topological germs"?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, category-theory, differential-topology

> **Definition 0.** By a *topological germ*, I mean a pointed topological space. Whenever $X$ and $Y$ denote topological germs, by a *morphism of topological germs $X \rightarrow Y$,* I mean a neighbourhood $U$ of $\bullet_X$, together with a basepoint-preserving continuous mapping $f : U \rightarrow Y$. Whenever $X$ and $Y$ denote topological germs, and $f,g : X \rightarrow Y$ are morphisms of topological germs, by a *neighbourhood of agreement* $p : f = g$, I mean a neighbourhood $U$ of $\bullet_X$ such that $f$ is defined on all of $U$, $g$ is defined on all of $U$, and $f\restriction_U = g\restriction_U$.

For example, there is a topological germ associated with $n$-dimensional Euclidean space; this is related to the concept of being "locally Euclidean" in the obvious way. More generally, let $X$ denote any topological space that is "homogeneous", in the sense that $\mathbf{Aut}(X)$ acts transitively on $X$. Then there is a germ $gX$ associated to $X$ in an obvious way.

> **Definition 1.** Topological germs can be organized into a $2$-category by taking morphisms of topological germs as $1$-cells, and neighbourhoods of agreement as $2$-cells. (To compose $2$-cells, take their intersection.) Call this $\mathbf{TopGerm}_2$. We can truncate to a $1$-category by declaring two morphisms two be equal iff there is a $2$-cell between them. Call this $\mathbf{TopGerm}_1$.

I'd like to know more:

> **Question.**
>
> Where can I learn more about what I'm denoting $\mathbf{TopGerm}_1$ and/or $\mathbf{TopGerm}_2$?

**Added 10/05/2016.** [This](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinitesimal+object) seems relevant.

Comment: What exactly do you want to learn about? The usual setting for this sort of thing outside the category category is with sheaves of sufficiently nice functions ($C^k$, smooth, analytic, etc.), with the germ appearing as the colimit with respect to restriction near a point; or in algebraic geometry, considering a sheaf axiomatically.

Comment: @anomaly, one of the first things I'd like to know is whether some analogue of the [CSB theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) holds in $\mathbf{TopGerm}_1$. Nothing like this holds for topological spaces; e.g. we can inter-embed $[0,1]$ and $(0,1)$ despite that they're non-homeomorphic. Even restricting to compact Hausdorff spaces doesn't work; we can inter-embed $[0,1]$ and $[0,1] \sqcup \{*\}$, despite that they're non homeomorphic. One hopes that these sorts of difficulties will go away if we're working only in some arbitrarily small neighbourhood.

Comment: If you had washed your hands after handling those filthy spaces you wouldn't have to worry about topological germs! :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila, nice :)

Comment: I have noticed that you have offered a bounty but received no answer. Maybe you might be interesting in my effort to collect somewhere unresolved bounties. For details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/23647/could-list-of-unresolved-past-bounties-be-useful/23715#23715) and [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/43020/2016/7/26).

Answer (score 0):

There's a brief mention of what I denote $\mathbf{TopGerm}_1$ above on p.39 of [this](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0168007293E0071U/1-s2.0-0168007293E0071U-main.pdf?_tid=d73cba9d-701d-432d-b21a-eadaa5975f93&acdnat=1540256387_8324d3d4291b284084c711fd77ef8c55) article on nonstandard analysis. The idea seems to be roughly that given a set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}^k$ together with a filter $\mathcal{F}$ on $A$, we get a corresponding topological space $X$ by defining $X := A \cup \{\infty\}$ as a set and declaring that $X \setminus \{\infty\}$ has the discrete topology, while using the filter $\mathcal{F}$ to give $\infty$ a non-trivial neighbourhood system. See the linked article for more information.